# Manhwa where the main character kills the son of a noble at night using magic

Tags: story-identification, manga, anime

There's a scene where the main character is traveling by carriage with his escort knights and he meets another son of a noble. They almost fight but then he leaves and go to a motel. He leaves at night and kills the kid he saw before using magic so no one could hear the guy scream and make it look like he left with a letter.and the knight that was protecting him later tried to check the mc power
More details:if i remember correctly he have 2 older brother and he can’t use magic but he can use mana and he demonstrate it to his father to be able to enter a magic academy

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You tagged this both "manga" and "anime."  Was it sequential art (manga) or an animated video (anime)?  Where and when did you read/see this?

Comment: The manhwa tag didn’t exist so put anime and manga but for me it was a manhwa so not anime and not manga sorry bout tht i think i read that a year ago, and idk if it help but i think the mc noble had a weak reputation then become op

Comment: @Jodelmar - Someone using an account with the same username as yours has attempted to edit this question. If that's you, you need to use the same account you used to post this question in order to edit it without approval from others. If you've lost access to that account, you can merge your new account with the previous one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). As well as enabling you to edit the question, you'll also regain the ability to leave comments in this thread and mark an answer as accepted if you wish to do so.

Comment: The "manga" tag covers any kind of asian comic, explicitly manga, manhwa, and manhua, but also the rare Vietnamese or other equivalent.

Comment: Ithink its because i setthe passworld on my phone and used my phone to edit it. Ty qazmlpok good to know

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the main character?